# Minitest: rake test:all fails while explicit testing does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a weird problem which is bugging me for days now... and I don't have a single clue.

I have a rails 4 app which i test using Minitest and guard. So far everything went fine until at some point (which unfortunately I'm not able to reconstruct although I was using guard, maybe my collaborators introduced the issues...) some of our tests fail. The weird thing is: `bundle exec rake test:all` fails:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: rake test:all is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. Use rake test to run all tests in test directory. (called from mon_synchronize at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214)

# Running tests with run options --seed 53809:

WARNING: The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.7.
............EE....EE.............F..

Finished tests in 26.018707s, 1.3836 tests/s, 1.6142 assertions/s.


Error:
PlaceTest#test_return_''_if_too_many_characters_to_translate:
NoMethodError: undefined method `failsafe_translate' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:PlaceTest>'

Error:
PlaceTest#test_test_places_are_valid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `geocode' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/place_geocode_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:PlaceTest>'

Error:
PlaceTest#test_should_translate_text_below_character_limit:
NoMethodError: undefined method `failsafe_translate' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb:34:in `block in <class:PlaceTest>'

Error:
PlaceTest#test_can_translate_if_valid_credentials_given:
NoMethodError: undefined method `bing_translator' for nil:NilClass
    test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:PlaceTest>'

Failure:
Index page Feature Test#test_0002_language is switched to german [/home/blubber/software_projects/rails/workspace/lberg-map/test/features/index_page_test.rb:16]
Minitest::Assertion: Expected to include "Neuer Ort".

36 tests, 42 assertions, 1 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

Now, while trying to understand the issues raised I was testing the problematic files individually (within my editor and guard or on the command-line, same thing of course) it turns out, that there is actually no problem at all, all tests pass oO. Hence `bundle exec rake test test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb` returns

```
# Running tests with run options --seed 55164:

.....

Finished tests in 25.472545s, 0.1963 tests/s, 0.2355 assertions/s.


5 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Same goes for `place_geocode_test.rb` as well as the "failing" feature test. Any idea on what's happening here? The test file `test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb` looks like this:

```
require_relative '../test_helper'

class PlaceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @valid_translator = BingTranslatorWrapper.new(ENV['bing_id'], ENV['bing_secret'], ENV['microsoft_account_key'])
    @place = Place.new(name: 'Kiezspinne',
                       street: 'Schulze-Boysen-Straße',
                       house_number: '13',
                       postal_code: '10365',
                       city: 'Berlin',
                       description_en: 'This is a test')
  end

  # AUTO TRANSLATION WRAPPER TESTS
  test 'can translate if valid credentials given' do
    assert_not_nil @valid_translator.bing_translator
  end

  test 'cannot translate if API id and key invalid or no microsoft account key' do
    invalid_translator = BingTranslatorWrapper.new(ENV['wrong_id'], ENV['wrong_secret'], ENV['microsoft_account_key'])
    assert_nil invalid_translator.bing_translator

    invalid_translator = BingTranslatorWrapper.new(ENV['bing_id'], ENV['bing_secret'], ENV['wrong_microsoft_account_key'])
    assert_equal '', invalid_translator.failsafe_translate('Dies ist ein Test', 'en', 'de')
  end

  test "return '' if too many characters to translate" do
    text = '13 characters' * 1000
    assert_equal '', @valid_translator.failsafe_translate(text, 'en', 'de')
  end

  test 'should translate text below character limit' do
    text = 'This is a test'
    assert_equal 'Automatische Übersetzung: Dies ist ein Test', @valid_translator.failsafe_translate(text, 'en', 'de')
  end

  test 'should autotranslate after_create' do
    @place.save
    @place.reload
    assert_equal "Automatische Übersetzung: Dies ist ein Test", @place.description_de
  end
end
```

and `test_helper.rb` looks like this

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/rails'
require 'minitest/reporters'
require 'minitest/rails/capybara'

reporter_options = { color: true }
Minitest::Reporters.use!(
  Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(reporter_options),
  ENV,
  Minitest.backtrace_filter
  )

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
end

Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)
Geocoder::Lookup::Test.set_default_stub(
  [
    {
      'latitude' => 52,
      'longitude' => 12,
      'address' => {
        'road' => 'Magdalenenstr.',
        'house_number' => '19',
        'postcode' => '10365',
        'town' => 'Berlin',
      },
      'type' => 'house',
    }
  ]
)

# allow tile loading from foreign server
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  %w[a b c].each { |x| config.allow_url("tile-#{x}.openstreetmap.fr") }
end
# While testing with Javascript flag, test runs in another thread,
# thus created fixtures are not available without the following setup
class Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  before do
    if metadata[:js]
      Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
      Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end
  end

  after do
    if metadata[:js]
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.default_driver
  end
end
```

Thanks a thousand, best
Andi

Comment: My guess is that one of your specs is altering `BingTranslatorWrapper` in some way, and doesn't set it back to its original state. Could you add a `binding.pry` (needs the `pry` gem) right before the line where one of you specs fail and see what is the `BingTranslatorWrapper` like?

Comment: Did it with byebugs `debugger`. First test in `test/models/place_auto_translation_test.rb` that fails has no access to the instance variable `@valid_translator` (== nil) if started via `rake test:all`. If executed via `rake test <path>` it works... Also, if i instanciate the class directly within every test (which for sure is not what I want) it also works... In what specific order are tests normally executed? I suspect that if sth. weird is being done to my class it happens before that test call

Comment: I don't know about minitest, but in rspec tests are executed at random. Yes, this is also what I think (another tests modifies this instance), since you get a `nil` value for your `BingTranslatorWrapper` constructor. It might be stubbed somewhere, but hard to say where from my side.